# Easiest way to call an Asp.Net webservice via https in a win forms app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

c# 4.7.2 asp.net classic webservice, connecting to webserivce using proxy generated by wsdl.exe via winforms.

I have web apps successfully connecting to the webservice, but I have a tool I wrote in c#/winforms, for testing if webservices are alive and working at various levels (dev/prod/etc)

What is the easiest way to call an .asmx webservice via https?

This is what it looks like now, but I'm okay with abandoning the proxy if that's easier

```
        AdStudent.ADStudent ws = new AdStudent.ADStudent();
        ws.Url = "https://jcdcadstudent.bob.org/adstudent.asmx";

        string str = ws.GetGuidString("Brown.Eric");
```

(Error = The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send)

On the web apps, just changing the url works, but not from a winform.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing something similar in WinForms, but I was sending requests to API, not MVC webapp, so I don't know if this will help, but I'll paste here one method of my WinForm App that was sending request to API:

```
private async void Timer1_Tick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var infos = new FirstEntity();
        infos.Num = 3;
        infos.Temp = 21;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(infos);
        var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var url = "https://localhost:7078/WeatherForecast";
        using var client = new HttpClient();

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry that was a miss statement contacting a classic asp.net webservice. That's fixed.
Is you code .net core? I dont' seem to have httpclient in .net 4.7.2 (Or jsonConvert)

Comment: I'm using .net 6 and only "using" I needed to include was using Newtonsoft.Json;

Answer (score 0):

The answer above did not work for me, I wound up doign it via soap, thusly

```
 static string GetData2(string url)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add( new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue( "text/xml" ) );
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add( "SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/GetGuidString" );

                       
            var soapXml= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?> " +
                "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
                    "<soap:Body>"+
                        "<GetGuidString xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"+
                            "<adUsername>Brown.Eric</adUsername>" +
                        "</GetGuidString>" +
                    " </soap:Body>" +
               "</soap:Envelope>";

            var response = httpClient.PostAsync( "https://jcdc-aeef.jcdev.org/JCDCADStudent/ADStudent.asmx", new StringContent( soapXml, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml" ) ).Result;

            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            return content;
        }
```

Check this url for detail on what tripped me up on the SOAP

[C# .netcore 3.1, calling asmx web service from a winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73653524/c-sharp-netcore-3-1-calling-asmx-web-service-from-a-winform?noredirect=1#comment130063662_73653524)

Hope it helps somebody!